# Error when trying to use reference.orderByChild() to get data from a realtime database in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

In my Android Studio Project I am trying to implement a function that after the user sign in, the app will get the name of the user, in the firebase realtime database, and get the names of the nodes where the child, "nomeProf", has as value the name of the user and set the text of a label as this names of nodes that it found.

[my firebase realtimedatabase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHE0j.png)

```
package com.example.classmob.fragment;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.classmob.R;
import com.example.classmob.RecyclerItemClickListener;
import com.example.classmob.activity.alunoActivity;
import com.example.classmob.activity.professorActivity;
import com.example.classmob.adapter.adapterSalas;
import com.example.classmob.model.ContentMain;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class salasFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView RecyclerView1;
    private List<ContentMain> serie = new ArrayList<>();
    private TextView txtSalas;
    private String nomeProf, salasAula="";
   // private Button btnTentar;
    private DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usuarios/");
    private DatabaseReference referenceSalas = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("salas/");

    ArrayList<String> aulaDada = new ArrayList<String>();

    public salasFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_salas, container, false);

        final Context context = view.getContext();
        txtSalas= view.findViewById(R.id.txtSalas);
        //btnTentar= view.findViewById(R.id.btnTeste);

        salas();

        return view; }

        public void salas(){
            FirebaseAuth autenticacao = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            String emailUsu= autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
            reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailUsu).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        nomeProf= datas.child("nome").getValue().toString();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            });
            if(nomeProf != null) {
                referenceSalas.orderByChild("nomeProf").equalTo(nomeProf).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            salasAula += datas.getKey();

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        throw databaseError.toException();
                    }
                });
                if (!salasAula.equals(""))
                    txtSalas.setText(salasAula);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "you dont teach any class yet"/*"Você não dá aula a nenhuma sala ainda"*/, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
}
```

I have tried with this code to do so, however it is not working and I dont know why. It always end up showing the toast messassege of "ERROR". How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting for the response, you're checking `nomeProf != null` before you query got an actual result. this is the way you have to do:

```
public void salas(){
            FirebaseAuth autenticacao = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            String emailUsu= autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
            reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailUsu).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        nomeProf= datas.child("nome").getValue().toString();


                    if(nomeProf != null) {
                referenceSalas.orderByChild("nomeProf").equalTo(nomeProf).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            salasAula += datas.getKey();

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        throw databaseError.toException();
                    }
                });
                if (!salasAula.equals(""))
                    txtSalas.setText(salasAula);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "you dont teach any class yet"/*"Você não dá aula a nenhuma sala ainda"*/, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            });

        }
```